# Weather warning data

Tags: data-request, weather, uk

Whilst there exist options to get [weather forecasts as open data](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/datagovuk/metofficeweatheropendata) I cannot seem to find anything relating to [weather](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/public/weather/warnings/#?tab=map&map=Warnings&zoom=5&lon=-3.50&lat=55.50&fcTime=1418688000) or [flood](http://apps.environment-agency.gov.uk/flood/142151.aspx) warnings.

Are current warnings or historical data available as open data in some geographical data format (such as ESRI shape files, or KML files)?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some US thoughts:

For US warnings/watches, you probably want to go the the storm prediction center,
http://www.spc.noaa.gov/wcm/
and you may want to look at the weather related shapefiles
http://www.nws.noaa.gov/geodata/
and the current alert system probably has an archive, but I didn't see it on first glance:
http://alerts.weather.gov/

I would suggest digging into the census tools related to disaster management.
http://onthemap.ces.census.gov/em/

The "on the map" product is a mashup of (1) weather data and (2) population/business data so that the impact of weather on population/businesses can be assessed.

It is only actual federally designated areas, I do not know if it has warnings/watches.

Comment: Whilst that's probably a great help for those in the US, I am primarily interested in the UK